# JuJu bootstrap Node type of AWS instance

Tags: juju

1) The default AWS instance for JuJu bootstrap seems to be an EC2 small.  Are there any disadvantages to making it a micro instance instead? What instance would be ideal in terms of cost and performance? (I may be running a storm topology on AWS via JuJu, if that helps. Don't know how large the cluster will be yet.)

2) JuJu bootstrap node on AWS has a 8GiB data volume automatically attached to it.  Is this necessary? What is it used for? Is there a way to deploy a bootstrap node without this data volume attached/alter the type of data volume?

I couldn't find any info. on these questions within the JuJu docs online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there's no such thing as a "tiny" I assume you mean a micro sized instance. `t2.micro`'s are burstable, and we've found through experience that micros are just too underpowered to run a bootstrap/state-server node.

If you're looking to save on cost then what you can do is run a workload on the bootstrap node, so that you effectively share a machine as both a coordination node and use it for real work. Perhaps also consider running Juju in HA mode so that you have a state server on multiple-nodes:

https://jujucharms.com/docs/stable/controllers-ha

This way you don't waste nodes but you don't have all your eggs in one basket either.

I'm not sure on the data volume, I'll ask and add that information when I get it.

Comment: Thank you.  I did mean micro instance.  I think running work load on bootstrap would be a good compromise.  Do you find the EC2 small instance for bootstrap to be adequate for most cases?

Comment: Unless you start going into the multiple-thousands of nodes the default small is fine.

Comment: Hey Jorge, did you ever find out about the data volume? Thanks